# Build Error in Mono Develop

Tags: c#, mono

I tried to build my existing Mvc application with Mono by changing targeting framework to Mono/.Net 4.5 in Mono Develop.
That gives me build error

> Build failed. Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Path'  Key being added: 'PATH'
>
> Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

I tried to make new project that also gave the same error.
I also tried to updating nuget package but that also did not works.

Comment: Mono on where? Windows? Linux? Which version of Mono? Did you build in MonoDevelop or with xbuild? Try xbuild at the terminal and see if it works.

Comment: _"if you can't help that's ok. but why close? "_ - whilst someone could potentially ask a question about _what's the airspeed of an unladen swallow_ and potentially also obtain an answer (even for _European_ swallows), it's probably off-topic for SO. :) See [ask]; and [faq].  Good luck!

Comment: what version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: @MickyD Strongly disagree with your assessment, this is a completely valid, programming-related question. This is a perfect fit in my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelWasser Poppycock.  If you can point out the problem in the OP's c# code or the definitive steps one must perform to solve the enigma that is perplexing the OP by way of c# revisions then I would agree that it's a _"completely valid, programming-related question"_. But since there is *no code* the latter will apply at 0.0000000000000000000s after the end of the universe.   QED

Comment: @MickyD building code is related to writing code. Whether or not there is code it the question, it is coding related ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is somewhat out of date, but I thought I'd include an answer to give folks a thread to follow.

I found several VS 2015 templates had elements in the projects that would cause this type of issue in sub-build files for mono. For example, references related to Rosyln or Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform. My particular project didn't need the latter, and I removed the related references to resolve the issue. The full error was

```
Error building target IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup: 
  Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Link'  Key being added: 'Link'
```

I figured out that this was related to my `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` by greping for the target, e.g.

```
grep IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup * -R
```

to find the offending package and figuring out if I could remove the code reference.

Comment: And what do you do after getting the result from `grep IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup * -R` ?